# iOS: Best way to Store Contact Info and GPS Coordinates

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, mkmapview, nsmutabledictionary, abaddressbook

I want to store specific info before adding it to my UITableView

I am accessing the End Users addressbook and getting the

```
First Name
Last Name
Street Address
City
State
Zip
```

Then I am using MKReverseGeocoder to get the GPS Coordinates

So I need to store the data from the addressbook and pair it to the GPS Coordinates that I received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `NSDictionary` (use `[NSMutableDictionary][1]`) and store it in the `[NSUserDefaults][2]`.

save:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:yourDictionary forKey:@"AkeyToUseAgainShouldBeAConstant"];
```

load:

```
NSDictionary *yourDictionary = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AkeyToUseAgainShouldBeAConstant"];
```

if you need it mutable again (to change the content)

```
NSMutableDictionary *yourDictionaryMutable = [[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AkeyToUseAgainShouldBeAConstant"] mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

Comment: How would I store 1 record in an NSMutableArray? Or would I use an array of arrays?